# How does one align a single row to the top in JQGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, paging

**JQGrid** is awesome for displaying data with **jQuery**, but it doesn't exactly have great documentation.

I'm having a problem with the grid when the grid has only one element to display.  For some reason, it's aligning the single row to the bottom rather than to the top.

Here's a picture of a **single misaligned row**:

[image: A single misaligned row]

Here are the jqgrid **options** I'm passing in:

```
jQGridOptions = {
            "recordtext": '{0} - {1} of {2}',
            "url": 'data.json',
            'datatype': 'json',
            'mtype': 'GET',
            'colModel': [
                { 'name': 'Rank', 'align': 'center', 'index': 'Rank', 'sortable': false, 'search': false },
                { 'name': 'Name', 'index': 'Name', 'sortable': false, 'search': true },
                { 'name': 'Score', 'index': 'Score', 'sortable': false, 'search': false }
            ],
            'pager': '#ranking-pager',
            'rowNum': 10,
            'altRows': true,
            'scrollOffset': 0,
            'colNames': ["Rank", "Name", "Score"],
            'width': 696,
            'height': 'auto', // '100%',  // 300,
            'page': 1,
            'sortname': 'Rank',
            'sortorder': "asc",
            'hoverrows': true,
            'viewrecords': true,
            'gridComplete': function () {
                $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').jScrollPane({ showArrows: true, scrollbarWidth: 17, arrowSize: 17, scrollbarMargin: 0 });

                if (selectedRank !== -1) {
                    selectRank(selectedRank);
                    selectedRank = -1;
                }
            },
            'jsonReader': {
               id : 'Rank',
               'repeatitems': false
        }
    };
```

As requested, here's the result from **data.json**:

```
{
    "page":1,
    "total":1,
    "records":1,
    "rows":  [{
                  "Name":"Gil Agostini",
                  "Score":94,
                  "Rank":1
             }]
}
```

**Call to jQGrid**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ranking-table").jqGrid(jQGridOptions);
});
```

**Html:**

```
 <div style="float: left;">
                <div class="hvy-border1">
                    <div class="hvy-border2">
                        <div class="hvy-top-left hvy-corner">
                            <div>
                                <!-- -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hvy-top-right hvy-corner">
                            <div>
                                <!-- -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear">
                            <!-- -->
                        </div>
                        <div id="table-and-pager" style="margin: 3px;">
                            <table id="ranking-table" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height: 300px">
                            </table>
                            <div id="ranking-pager" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear">
                            <!-- -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="hvy-bottom-left hvy-corner">
                            <div>
                                <!-- -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hvy-bottom-right hvy-corner">
                            <div>
                                <!-- -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can anyone give me any clue what I maybe doing wrong here?

How do I get the row to align to the top rather than the bottom?

Comment: Could you insert contain of the JSON response `data.json` having the row? Do you have the same results if you don't use `jScrollPane` plugin and don't call `selectRank` function?

Comment: Commenting out  selectRank or the jScrollPane part of that function does not seem to have any noticable effect at all.

Comment: Still needing answers, I reasked this question at the jqGrid forum here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/how-does-one-align-a-single-row-to-the-top-in-jqgrid/#p21794

Comment: Small typing error in your code: you need include comma which decides `gridComplete` and `jsonReader` parameters.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for taking the time to point that out.  I will correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not reproduce the problem which you describes. I suppose that you use some additional setting for jqGrid: you don't post the whole JavaScript code of your example.

Nevertheless I can definitively say that you has some problems in the format of the JSON data returned from the server. Important is that every row of data must has an unique id. For example

```
{ "id":123, "Name":"Gil Agostini", "Score":94, "Rank":1 }
```

instead of

```
{ "Name":"Gil Agostini", "Score":94, "Rank":1 }
```

The `id` can has also string type and not be only numeric. Moreover you have to define [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) parameter of jqGrid, because your data has **named elements instead of the standard array of strings** (which is more compact and small data). In the case you should at least use `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}`.

If some other grid column (like the `Name` column) can be interpret as the id, you can either include `key:true` in the corresponding column definition or use `id:'Name'` as a property of the `jsonReader`.

For example the following `jsonReader`

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    id: 'Name'
}
```

can be used to read your current JSON data (see live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MarkRogers.htm)). Using any tool which you prefer you can verify the `id` value of the `<tr>` element of the grid.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the JsonReader when I cut and paste my code into the question.   I added it back into the question.  Is there anymore javascript or css code you would like?

Comment: None of the changes you suggest here, had any effect.  jQGrid did not act differently whether i had, id: 'Rank' or not.

Comment: @Mark Rogers: you should remove `style="height: 300px"` from the `<table id="ranking-table"` element. If you need define the grid height you should change `height:'auto'` option to `height:300`. Other settings like `class="scroll"` and so on are also obsolete. I recommend you to use just `<table id="ranking-table"></table><div id="ranking-pager"></div>` or include additional `<tr><td/></tr>` inside of `<table>` element to be conform to XHTML standard. The example http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MarkRogers1.htm is more close to your code. The usage of `id` is important in other situations.

Comment: @Mark Rogers: If your data not contain `id`, you will still able to display the data, but the `<tr>` elements will have ids starting with 1. If you have two grids on one page filled in the way you will have id conflicts. Of cause you can not use any other HTML elements with the integer ids because the same reason. If you will need use local data editing you will has real problems if you not has unique row ids. So in simplest cases you can display jqGrid with the data without ids, but I strictly recommend you don't do this.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks a lot for that information, I will do as you wisely advise.  In this particular situation there was only one grid on the page.

Comment: @Mark Rogers: Then if you remove `style="height: 300px"` and replace `height:'auto'` option to `height:300` if needed then your problem will be solved. If the problem still having you should post the CSS definitions of all classes which you use.

Comment: @Oleg ha, it worked, your a f'in genius.  Bravo sir, could you mention your solution in your answer so that others may learn from my error.

Comment: @Mark Rogers: You welcome! I am glad to hear that I could help you. Also thanks for the good words about my answers.